# Swift compilation error : swift failed with exit code 254 (Xcode6 Beta4, Beta5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

If I uncomment my dictionary iteration code as,

```
for (key, value) in dicParamDetails
{
    var sKey : String = "list[0][\(key)]"
    dicParam[sKey] = value as? String
}
```

I'm getting :

```
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

And If I comment my dictionary iteration code as,

```
//      for (key, value) in dicParamDetails
//      {
//          var sKey : String = "list[0][\(key)]"
//          dicParam[sKey] = value as? String
//      }
```

Project compiles, and works.

What's so wrong in this key, value iteration? (FYI - same code works in one of my another class)

**UPDATE :** Eventually found that issue was with dicParam,

It was declared as

```
 var dicParam = [MY_KEY: MY_VALUE]
```

Which is not working.

changed to,

```
var dicParam : [String : AnyObject]  = [MY_KEY: MY_VALUE]
```

Which complies and works.

(Same for xCode6 beta5)

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: And test on beta 5 before you file that bug.